# create a new file if doesn't exist

Tags: c++, file, createfile

This is my `main.cpp`:

```
int main () {
    FILE* file_name;
    file_name= fopen("email1.clear","wb");
return 0;
}
```

I run it with the ssh (Linux):

```
g++ main.cpp -o main
```

but no file has been created. (I must to use: FILE*).

please help.

Comment: Your command isn't actually running anything, it's just compiling. You need to run your programm with ./main

Comment: what does it mean? g++ ./main?

Comment: @user1961415: Just `./main`. The program can run by itself and doesn't really need something like an interpreter you would know from e.g. bash, Python, Perl, ..

Answer (score 2):

**> `How Do I Compile/Run My Program?`**

To compile C/CPP program first.cpp, and create an executable file called first, enter:

```
$ gcc first.cpp -o first
```

**OR**

```
$ cc first.cpp -o first
```

To execute program first, enter:

```
$ ./first
```

Comment: Either your C files have an unusual extension or you wrongly use a C compiler to compile C++ code.

Comment: @honk, `gcc` is smart enough and runs the C++ frontend when the file extension is `.cpp`.

Comment: @HristoIliev: Still confusing style.

Answer (score 0):

Well I recomend that you use `"a+"` instead of `wb` first of all because `"a+"` let's you create a file if it doesn't exist and if it does it let's you add stuff in the file. Second well I don't know if you are going to use binary because the `b` in `wb` is for binary don't put it if you don't need it. So your code should look something like this:

```
int main () {
    FILE* file_name;
    file_name= fopen("email1.clear","a+");//or just use "w" bot work
return 0;
}
```

also the file might been placed where the .cpp is save they are usually saved together.